# How to compare values in array to find one or more matches in another array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I try compare two arrays to find one or more than one matches of them.
Somebody help me please?

http://jsfiddle.net/gmRDk/2/

```
$("button").click(function(i) {

var products = [2, 5, 6, 7, 200];
var item_id = [2, 1, 6, 200];

$.each(item_id, function() {
if ($.inArray(this, products) !== -1) {
    alert('Match Prod: ' + this);
} else {
    alert('Not Match: ' + this);
}
});
});
```

Comment: You need at least two loops to find matches, taking each element from one and comparing with the other. It will be better if you try it out and post what kind of errors you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the each callback `this` points to a object, not to the value

```
var products = [2, 5, 6, 7, 200];
var item_id = [2, 1, 6, 200];
$.each(item_id, function(idx, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value, products) !== -1) {
        console.log('Match Prod: ' + value);
    } else {
        console.log('Not Match: ' + value);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2kqE4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("button").click(function(i) {

  var products = [2, 5, 6, 7, 200];
var item_id = [2, 1, 6, 200];
    var len=products.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
  if($.inArray(products[i],item_id)==-1)
  {
      alert("not in array item_Id   :"+products[i]);
  }
        else{
            alert("in array item_ID  :"+products[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

you can check each individual element in the array like this .
demo :http://jsfiddle.net/gmRDk/3/